# RealmSwift @ObservedResults with parent and child models, cannot modify managed RLMArray outside of a write transaction

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I am trying to display some simple Realm objects in a SwiftUI list. Each object also has related child objects.

I am able to display the parent objects just fine by using the `@ObservedResults(Parent.self)` property wrapper. Simply adding or removing the parent objects to/from Realm updates the list and this works great.

The problem occurs when I want to display the related child models. When I attempt to add the child models in Realm the same way I added the parent models, also using the default Realm.Configuration, I get an `RLMException` saying `Cannot modify managed RLMArray outside of a write transaction.`

Here is a simple SwiftUI view that illustrates the problem.

```
struct ContentView: View {    
    
    @ObservedResults(Parent.self) var parents
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 15) {
            Button("Create parents") {
                let realm = try! Realm()
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.add(Parent(id: 1, name: "Nick"), update: .all)
                    realm.add(Parent(id: 2, name: "Lucas"), update: .all)
                    realm.add(Parent(id: 3, name: "Ryan"), update: .all)
                }
            }
            Button("Create child") {
                guard let parent = parents.first else {
                    return
                }
                let realm = try! Realm()
                try! realm.write {
                    let child = Child(id: parent.children.count + 1, name: "Foo")
                    parent.children.append(child)
                }
            }
            Button("Delete all") {
                let realm = try! Realm()
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.deleteAll()
                }
            }
            List(parents) { parent in
                VStack {
                    Text(parent.name)
                    ForEach(parent.children){ child in
                        Text("Child: \(child.name)")
                            .padding(.leading, 10)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here are my models:

```
class Parent: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    
    var children = List<Child>()
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
 
    convenience init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Child: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    
    private let parents = LinkingObjects(fromType: Parent.self, property: "children")
        
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    
    convenience init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

By clicking the buttons `Create parents` and `Delete all` you see the parent models appear and disappear as expected. Clicking `Create child` produces the error.

I'm really at a loss here, any help with this is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please add code to the question. It's hard to read as a comment.

Comment: I would suggest for testing, don't use the RealmHelper. Try just getting the realm and then writing to it. `let realm = Realm()` and then `try! realm.write {` and see if that works.

Comment: Edited my question with your suggestion. Still produces the error. @Jay

Comment: Cool. I just noticed the @ ObservedResults - so yes, you'll probably want to thaw the parent object and also get the same realm the parent was created on like this `let thawedRealm = thawedParent.realm()` and then `try! thawedRealm.write`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question. It seems you have to `thaw` the parent model (whatever that means) before appending any children to it. I couldn't find this mentioned in the docs anywhere so it might be a bug.

Anyways, here is the fix:

```
Button("Create child") {
    guard let parent = parents.first?.thaw() else {
        return
    }
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        let child = Child(id: parent.children.count + 1, name: "Foo")
        parent.children.append(child)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The reasoning is that Realm offers [freeze and thaw](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/advanced-guides/threading/#frozen-objects)  which allows realm objects to be shared between threads in a thread-safe way. Realm does not allow live objects to be shared between threads, so to di that the object(s) (and its child objects) can be frozen. It's essentially a snapshot of the object - and when it's thawed, it becomes live again. So I don't think that *thaw* is being used correctly here because it was not *frozen* to begin with.

Comment: You may be right, and I would welcome a better solution if you have one! @Jay

Comment: See my comment/suggestion to your question and report back the results.

Comment: I have tried your comment with the same exception being thrown.

Comment: @Jay fwiw - I learned this method from a post here: https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/realm-object-update-with-swiftui/104143/10 made by a mongodb employee..

Comment: The problem is the error message you're reporting `Cannot modify managed RLMArray` is unrelated to the code in the question *if* you write to realm in the way I suggested as you are not writing any kind of Collection (RLMArray). Can you please add additional code in your question showing how you implemented my suggestion? Oh, and remove `private` from the LinkingObjects object as well.

Comment: Oh btw - I was on that discussion thread. You need to get the same realm the object was created on.

Comment: Please feel free to provide a better working solution if you have one. I've tried everything on that thread and so far this is the only thing that works.